# Responsive drop-down menu from burger of navbar using Javascript toggle works in Chrome, Firefox, but not Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a responsive navbar using toggle in Javascript. The navbar appears after scrolling down 70vh. At a max-width of 768px, the responsiveness kicks in and a burger appears with a dropdown menu when clicked.

Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox- when both manually adjusting the size of the browser and using the browsers' mobile device emulators. But in Safari and on actual mobile devices (iPad, iPhone 7, iPhone 5), the navbar appears with the burger, when I click the burger it transforms to an 'X' as it's suppose to, but the drop-down menu does not appear.

Edit to clarify: If you view the code snippet below, this is what should happen. This is what does happen in Chrome and Firefox, but not on actual mobile devices. Rather, on a mobile device, when I press the burger, it turns into an 'X', but the drop-down menu does not slide onto the screen.

I've spent more than a day trying to figure out what is going on. My HTML head has the appropriate meta tag for mobile device width, and I've tried using the appropriate -moz, -webkit, -o properties for every animation, transform, transition, and keyframe in CSS. I cannot find a solution. Someone please throw me a life vest, I'm sinking.

Here's my code:

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
  // Toggle Nav
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = ''
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 5 + 0.5}s`;
    }
  });
  // Burger Animation
  burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
}

navSlide();

// navbar appears after scrolling
let navbar = document.querySelector(".header-navigation");
if (navbar) {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= window.innerHeight - 70) {
      navbar.classList.add('navbar-show');
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove('navbar-show')
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-navigation {
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  color: black;
  background-color: #5D4954;
  text-align: right;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 12px 0px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 12px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
/*  font-weight: bold; */
}

.burger {
  display: none;
}

.burger div{
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  .nav-links {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  body{
/*    overflow-x: hidden;
*/  }
  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #5D4954;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
      -o-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
      -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
      -o-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    -moz-animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    -o-animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    -ms-animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  cursor: pointer;
/*  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

.banner {
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner h1 {
  padding-top: 300px;
}

.container1 {
  height: 92vh;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container2 {
  height: 92vh;
  background: grey;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>NAVIGATIOn</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:200,300,400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header-navigation">
      <nav class="nav">
        <div class="logo">
          <h4>NAV</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">Why a Website?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="banner">
      <h1>Banner</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <h1>Container1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
      <h1>Container2</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.nav-active { transform: translateX(0); -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }` without percent on a `0` value (0% is invalid), and the `-webkit-` prefix. I don't have time to go make a codepen to test or something but would be my first guess of your culprit. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I tried this but it didn't work. I've tried -webkit, -moz, and -o on every transform, translation, and keyframe in the CSS file. Unfortunately, none of it worked.

Comment: Ah gotcha, another shot in the dark would be to add `display: block;` to `.nav-links a
`

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried this as well but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something seems messed up with the overflow. Try to not use overflow-hidden in your .navbar-show

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RomanVanLoo/5ohva732/6/

```
body {


margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-navigation {
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  color: black;
  background-color: #5D4954;
  text-align: right;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 12px 0px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 4px 12px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
/*  font-weight: bold; */
}

.burger {
  display: none;
}

.burger div{
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  .nav-links {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  body{
/*    overflow-x: hidden;
*/  }
  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #5D4954;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
      -o-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
      -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
      -o-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    -moz-animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    -o-animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    -ms-animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    animation: navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  cursor: pointer;
/*  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

.banner {
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner h1 {
  padding-top: 300px;
}

.container1 {
  height: 92vh;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container2 {
  height: 92vh;
  background: grey;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prefix -webkit-transition and -webkit-transform in order to work for mobile.
For compatibility in all supporting browsers, vendor prefixes are required, with the standard syntax declared last:

```
.example {
-webkit-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
-moz-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
-o-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s; }
```

Comment: Thanks- I've tried this in every order possible for every transform, transition, animation, and keyframe in the CSS file. Nothing worked. To clarify, the responsiveness of this code works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox on a desktop, but not on Safari on a desktop nor safari on an iPad, iPhone 7, or iPhone 5. To be even more clear, the navbar appears on the aforementioned mobile devices, the burger changes to an x when pressed, and at that same time, a menu is suppose to slide onto the screen, right to left. But this latter part doesn't happen.